# Move an email from one folder to another folder

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I want to move an email from A folder to Folder B. Program should take parameters like source folder Id , folder name and email unique id similarly for  destination folder.

Note- Sometime folder may contain sub folders within , program should traverse to the specified folder name and folder id and move the email into appropriate location.

I did moving complete mails from one folder to another , but failed to do it for individual emails.

```
if (folder.getDisplayName().equals("Inbox")) {
    FolderId fid = folder.getId();
    System.out.println("Folder Id - "+ fid);

    for(Item item : findResult.getItems()){
        System.out.println("item - " + item.getId()); 

        item.load();
        item.move(fid);
    }                       
}
```

Comment: Assuming the code you've posted shows how you move all emails (items?) to the folder `fid`, what's the problem with doing it just for one item? Besides that, what would happen to `folder.getDisplayName().equals("Inbox")` if the locale was changed to something other than English? I'd assume the display name depends on the locale, doesn't it?

Comment: is there any direct search of an Item in folder and pick that item and move to destination folder. Each time traversing complete folder for one item will be tedious process I think

Comment: Well as a general rule you should first make it work then make it work fast. If there is a seemingly tedious way (in terms of performance) that you know then use that first. You might find that there's not as big a performance problem as you might think and even if there is one you'd probably have learned a few things to make it easier to find or devise improvements.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said,

> Sometime folder may contain sub folders within , program should traverse to the specified folder name and folder id and move the email into appropriate location

Completing your goal depends on `findResult.getItems()`, which is not shown here. 
You may want to check for recursiveness regarding what you are trying to achieve.

As you have said, moving is successful for all emails but having problem for individual emails, it points to details of getItems() implementation.

Comment: Hi Pranay , could you pls able to give me complete method which performs required operation

Comment: @Karthiktn since you should be able to maintain that code in the future and probably learn a thing or two as well giving you the entire code wouldn't make sense (and we're not a gimme-teh-codez service anyway). We're here to provide hints and explanations but you should still put some effort into the solution yourself.